# Taxes working remotely from Portugal or Spain for an Irish company

Tags: taxes, freelance

The Irish company I work for offered me to work remotely 100%.  I think it would be a good idea to move and work in a place with better weather and cheaper life.

I am mainly considering Spain and Portugal but I am afraid to incur heavy taxation. I know that both countries offer discounted taxes for new residents.

Can someone tell me how much taxes should I pay on those countries with a salary of around 60K euro?

Comment: Note that tax isn't the only relevant factor. You may find it difficult to pay social security, in which case you'll want private health insurance.

Comment: Don't forget about healthcare and social security costs too.  These are often separate from "tax", but can take a big chunk of your pay.

Answer (score 1):

KPMG show the tax bands for each countries:

[Spain](https://home.kpmg.com/xx/en/home/insights/2011/12/spain-income-tax.html)

> €0 to €12,450 is taxed at 19%
>
> €12,450 to €20,200 is taxed at 24%
>
> €20,200 to €35,200 is taxed at 30%
>
> €35,200 to €60,000 is taxed at 37%
>
> €60,000 and over is taxed at 45%

[Portugal](https://home.kpmg.com/xx/en/home/insights/2011/12/portugal-income-tax.html)

> €0 to €7091 is taxed at 14.5%
>
> €7091 to €10,700 is taxed at 24%
>
> €10,700 to €20,261 is taxed at 38.5%
>
> €20,261 to €25,000 is taxed at 35%
>
> €25,000 to €36,856 is taxed at 37%
>
> €36,856 to €80,640 to  is taxed at 45%
>
> €80,640 and over is taxed at 48%

There are several online tax calculators for Spain (e.g. [Salary after Tax](https://salaryaftertax.com/es) & [Spanish income tax calculator](https://www.icalculator.info/spain.html) which give "take home pay" figures of €41,405 & €42,314) but I couldn't find a decent one for Portugal.

Comment: As a non habitual resident Portugal offers a 20% cap for a list of approved professions for 10 years